# Using angular-ui-router can I have multiple states simultaneously?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I'm trying to accomplish is showing the user a page-creation wizard in a lightbox/modal without the underlying page disappearing just because I'm moving from the page state to the wizard state; I want to have both.

The underlying page can have any number of underlying states, and the wizard should be accessible in each, so it's not really practical to add the wizard states as children to all page states. So conceptually I'd like to have combined states like (page.comment, wizard.step1). Is something like that possible with angular-ui-router?

Answer (score 1):

As I know AngularUI Router could provide multiple views.
Did you read Wiki? There is tons of useful information.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Multiple views is not the trouble; multiple states is. I don't want make `#pagestates x #wizardstates` states if it can be avoided.

Comment: Read about nested states.

Comment: I have. But I'd rather have (say) 20+10 than 20X10 states, if possible. It's rather a lot of work to nest all wizard states beneath all page states. Though I suppose I could write a function to create the cartesian product of both sets of states, if it comes to that.

Answer (score 1):

A state with different sub views are different states and thats what the previous answer meant, but you don't need a state to have multiple components/controller on the same state/view. For example, instead of trying to control the wizard with state, you could simply use state parameters.